# File missing when trying to do a full build of TFS Cube

Tags: tfs, cube

I am trying to do a full rebuild of my TFS Cube.  We went through the steps listed in the [Rebuild the data warehouse and cube](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/admin/rebuild-data-warehouse-and-cube) doc to recreate it.

But then, by mistake, we used SSMS to try to process the cube.

We then realized our error and tried the steps listed in the [Manually process the TFS data warehouse and analysis services cube](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/admin/manually-process-data-warehouse-and-cube) doc to do a full rebuild of the data.

When I do that I get the following error:

> 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS11.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Backup\Tfs_Analysis 1.0.db\Team System.67.cub\v Fact Linked Current Work Item Test Case.67.det\v Fact Linked Current Work Item Test Case.66.prt\67.WorkItem Link Type.TeamProjectCollectionSK.fact.map'
>
> : The system cannot find the path specified

In that file path is `Team System.67.cub`.  That is where the path goes wrong.  There is a file called `Team System.3.cub`.  3, not 67.

And when I tried to run again, the error changed the file name to `Team System.77.cub`, but the directory still only had `Team System.3.cub`.

**Is there a way past this?  Or did processing the Cube using SSMS mess it up such that I need to start over?**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to delete the Tfs_Analysis database and recreate it using TFS Admin Console. To delete the Tfs_Analysis database, you can connect to Analysis Service using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, expand the Databases node, and delete the Tfs_Analysis database.  (Backup first in case meed any issuses.)

To recreate the Tfs_Analysis database, please refer to the following steps:

1. Launch TFS Admin Console>>Application Tier>>Reporting, in the right
   panel, click Edit to open the Reporting windows.
2. Under the Analysis Services tab, input the Tfs_Analysis
   under Database textbox, and re-provide the required account under
   Account for accessing data source.
3. Click Ok to generate the Tfs_Analysis database in Analysis Services.
4. Click Start Jobs and Start Rebuild to rebuild warehouse and the
   Analysis Services database.